# Set default UIScrollView scale

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm using a UIScrollView with

```
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.8;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=1.8;
```

However, when the view loads, it loads at a 1.0 scale by default.

I'd like to load at 0.8 instead. Setting `self.scrollView.zoomScale = 0.8;` doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks

*Problem solved. You can set the  zoomScale property, however, you must set it AFTER all your scrollView content is loaded.

Comment: In which method do you call the zoomscale setters?

Comment: Hi, I solved the issue, turns out zoomScale works, you just have to set the value after all the content inside your scrollview has loaded.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to point out in my next response. Great that you solved it :)!

Comment: Remember to post your answer and accept it, when the option becomes available :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the zoomScale property, however, you must set it AFTER all your scrollView content is loaded.